# Realloc error in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, void, realloc

I've just started C read the man page but could not find the proper answer. So the code is below

```
void *p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
int *q = p;
int NUMOFINT = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < NUMOFINT; i++){
printf("%i ", q[i]);
}
void *realloc(void *p, 20*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
printf("%i ", q[i]);
```

and it is giving this error:

```
malloc.c: In function ‘main’:
malloc.c:31:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

I did not quite understand that the size format was ok for `malloc()` but not ok for realloc. So how do I correct the error?

Edit:

so when I make it as:

```
void *morep = realloc(p, 20*sizeof(int));
int *q2 = morep;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
printf("%i ", q2[i]);
}
```

it prints out `q2[11]` as `135121`

Comment: Call to realloc is all messed, maybe something like `void *new_p = realloc(p, 20*sizeof(int));` ?. You have not declared a pointer to hold the return of `realloc` & you are (re)declaring a pointer `p` when making a call to the function.

Comment: Would that reallocate the actual p void?

Comment: Yes, please refer to function [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html) or `man` pages if you are on *nix system for more details

Comment: Also, that second for loop should really be 20, not 21. You don't want to read p[20] when it's size 20.

Comment: Your `realloc` line looks like a mix between a prototype and a call. You do not need a prototype (it is in the header `<stdlib.h>`) and the call should look like `tmp = realloc(oldpointer, <NEW_SIZE>); if (!tmp) /* error */; oldpointer = tmp;`

Comment: Hi, I realised something. If i want to print q[11] then it prints it as 135121, rather than 0.

Comment: That's because `q[]` was never initialized. Malloced memory contains indeterminate values. In fact, using indeterminate values is undefined behavior. If you want zeroized memory, use `calloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
void *realloc(void *p, 20*sizeof(int));
```

is wrong. You want

```
p = realloc(p, 20*sizeof(int));
```

Incidentally, this line is also a problem (but will compile fine):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
```

You allocated p to 20*sizeof(int) bytes, so element 20 is past the end of the array. You want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to assign the results of `realloc` to the same old pointer, because if the reallocation fails, `0` will be assigned to `p` and you will lose your pointer to the old memory, which will in turn leak.

Comment: This way still prints q2[11] as 135121, not as 0

Comment: `q2[11]` could be anything. `morep` is pointing to uninitialized memory. You haven't assigned anything to it. Try `memset (q2, 0, 20*sizeof(int))`, or make a for loop and assign values to each element of `q2`.

Comment: But It happened the same with your code as well.
what I want is, when I reallocate the array, the new part should come as all 0s rather than whatever is stored in that memory previously...

Comment: @SarpKaya: The C lib standard does not agree with you.  It is your responsibility to set the newly allocated block of memory to meet your needs...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int *temp;  /* To use with realloc, it's more secure */
        void *p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        int *q = p;
        int NUMOFINT = 10;

        /* dont forget to compile with -std=99 flag, if you use this kind of for loop */
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMOFINT; i++){
                printf("%i ", q[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        /* It's more secure to use this kind of realloc */
        temp = realloc (p, 20 * sizeof(int) );
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"Reallocation failed --> %s\n", strerror(errno));
                free(p);

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
                p = temp;
        }

        /* Zeroing after realloc */
        for (int i = NUMOFINT; i < 21; i++)
                q[i] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
                printf("%i ", q[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` can tries to expand the existing memory block in heap, if its not possible it will allocate a new separate block of memory for the new size and it will copy the data from old memory block to the new memory block also.

So if realloc returns the address same as `p` then it just expands the old memory block. Or else we have to free the old memory block and start using the new memory block returned by `realloc`.

```
#define NUMOFINT 10
#define NUMOFINT_NEW 20

void *p = malloc(NUMOFINT * sizeof(int)); 
int *q = p; 
void *temp = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < NUMOFINT; i++)
{ 
    printf("%i ", q[i]); 
} 

temp = realloc(p, NUMOFINT_NEW * sizeof(int)); 
if (temp == NULL)
{
    exit(0);
}
else if (temp != p)
{
    free(p);
    p = temp;
}

//else temp is equal to p

for (int i = 0; i < NUMOFINT_NEW; i++)
{ 
    printf("%i ", q[i]); 
}
```

Here `q[0]` to `q[9]` will have the values(`0, 1, 2..9`) assigned, and the rest (`q[10]` to `q[19]`) will have garbage value. We have not `memset` the newly allocated memory to `0` also.

you can memset also before `for loop`,

```
memset((q + NUMOFINT), 0, (NUMOFINT_NEW - NUMOFINT));
```

### Mistakes in your program are

1) compilation error because
`void *realloc(void *p, 20*sizeof(int));` This statement doesn;t looks like a function call.

2) `for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)` - After memory is realloced to `20` elements, you can access only upto `19th`, accessing `20th` may leads to crash(undefined behaviour).

3) `it prints out q2[11] as 135121` - Newly reallocated memory is neither `memset` to `0` nor assigned any meaningful values.